# Get values of XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I know that we have a lot of topics  about xml but i cant get this to work.
I have this xml:

```
<OrderRoot>
   <Order>
     <Client>Company Company</Client>
     <Cod>0000</Cod>
   </Order>
   <Itens>
     <Item Sequence="01">
       <Product>54321</Product>
       <Description>xxxxxxx</Description>
     </Item>
     <Item Sequence="02">
       <Product>12345</Product>
       <Description>xxxxxxx</Description>
     </Item>
     <Item Sequence="03">
       <Product>123456</Product>
       <Description>xxxxxxx</Description>
     </Item>      
   </Itens>
 </OrderRoot>
```

My Code:

```
   order.Client = xmlDocument.Descendants("Client").First().Value;
   order.A1_Codigo = xmlDocument.Descendants("Cod").First().Value;

   foreach (XElement item in xmlDocument.Descendants("Itens"))
   {
       //EDITed
       var aux = item.Element("Product").Value; //Get the null reference exception here.
   }
```

But i get always system null reference in the foreach loop. The order before works fine.

What im doing wrong here?

Comment: where exactly is `pedido` defined? because right now, that's your null reference.

Comment: sorry, i edited. Order is a object with a list of itens inside and other properties.

Comment: Okay, so debug your code and find out what's null and why. With such a small window, it is *extremely* difficult for us to tell you what's wrong. You haven't even told us which line and what object is null either.

Comment: Have you instantiated the `Itens` property in order?

Comment: yes i have it in the constructor.

Comment: Ive edited the post, i get the null reference in the aux property.

Comment: Like I said **use your debugger**. That is the greatest tool for you here, not StackOverflow. What is null? `item`? Does `item.Element("Product")` return null? That should tell you where to start looking to find out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product is not a direct child of Itens, and that's why you're getting an exception. Try changing you loop source:

```
foreach (XElement item in xmlDocument.Descendants("Itens").Elements("Item"))
```